# What's wrong with the C code below?(A trivial one)

Tags: c, sum

When you run the C code below, you get a different results almost everytime(None of them are altogether correct).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int s[10][4]={{202201,90,13,21},{202202,32,24,12},{202203,23,53,76},{202204,21,43,64},{202205,12,45,89},{202206,98,99,100},{202207,12,0,0},{202208,0,0,0},{202209,98,12,34},{202210,23,65,34}};
    int ave[10],sum[10];
    printf("No.     MA  EN  CN\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            printf("%4d",s[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<4;j++)
            sum[i]=s[i][j]+sum[i];
    printf("%d\n",sum[i]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

What's happening? What's the mechanics behind it? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where did you initialize the elements of `sum` (or `ave`) to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `sum` and `ave` are uninitialized arrays. That means that when you cumulative add to `s[i]` your first add to an uninitialized value which invokes Undefined Behaviour. Here you were just getting a random but valid value.

You need to ensure that `s[i][j]` is initialized to 0 before it is first used:

```
int ave[10],sum[10] = {0}; // initialize the full sum array to 0
```

or:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    sum[i] = 0;      // ensure an initial value of 0
    for(j=1;j<4;j++)
        sum[i]=s[i][j]+sum[i];
    printf("%d\n",sum[i]);
}
```

Comment: Re “an uninitialized value which invokes Undefined Behaviour”: The code shown uses indeterminate values and does not have undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that `int ave[10],sum[10] = {0}` does not initialize `ave`. Not necessarily required depending on how the averages are calculated, of course.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Could not an unitialized variable contain a trap value?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Not in C implementations without trap values, and that is a separate issue from whether using an uninitialized object has undefined behavior. One would not say `a+b` has undefined behavior just because it could have values that overflow, so one should not say `a[b]` has undefined behavior just because it could (in a different C implementation) have a trap value. The core behavior of `a+b` or `a[b]` with `a[b]` uninitialized is defined, so neither `a+b` nor `a[b]` with `a[b]` uninitialized has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely is in this statement.

```
sum[i]=s[i][j]+sum[i];
```

The "sum" integer array hasn't been initialized prior to this statement, so the value "sum[i]" on the right-hand side of the statement probably holds undefined data.  Either initialize your sum array or revise the statement if some other type of evaluation should occur.

Comment: Re “probably holds undefined data”? Probably? Do you think there is some percentage of chance that it holds specified data?